# Enable/disable Daylight Savings Time through command line on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: datetime, ubuntu, command-line, timezone, dst

Note: By "Disable" daylight savings time, I mean for the system clock to ignore any time changes for daylight savings time (ie, if DST is disabled, then the clock will not "spring forward" an hour in March and will not "fall back" an hour in November.

I am designing an Qt application to run on Ubuntu 18.04 and I need to be able to set system timezone, time and date.

For settings time and date, I can easily use [timedatctl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/timedatectl.1.html) to modify the system settings. However, this command does seem to be able to disable Daylight Savings Time. It does report whether DST is "Active" or not depending on the timezone and date, but you cannot disable/enable this settings.

On Windows, I had used [tzutil.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tzutil) to setting DST enabled or not using the dst_off flag. Is there are any equivalent to Ubuntu?

Comment: This Q is more appropriate to https://askubuntu.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com or even https://superuser.com  Please delete here and repost to the forum that makes the most sense after reading their 'On-Topic' Help section. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thanks for the response. [I posted on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157307/enable-disable-daylight-savings-time-through-command-line) and was suggested to post here.

Comment: LOL, so the stackexchange circle continues! Sorry! I would definitely try https://unix.stackexchange.com next. Good luck.

Comment: This can be discussed on either site.  AskUbuntu has more focus on Ubuntu (of course), but Stack Overflow is more focused on app development - which it seems like is part of your second paragraph (you should expand on the programming side of this point, if possible).  Also StackOverflow has a more active [tag:timezone] tag (9,374 questions vs 86).  Time zones in computing are on-topic here.

Comment: My question is: given ubuntu uses the Olson timezone database, is it even possible to "turn off" DST for a timezone that uses DST?

Comment: @glennjackman That is the golden question. From my research, I'm guessing the answer is no. But I will try unix.stackexchange and see what they have to say.

Comment: Writing an answer now (here)... hang on. :)

Comment: Why does your application care about the _system_ time zone?  Isn't it sufficient to set the _process's_ time zone to one that suits you, e.g. by setting `TZ` in its environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer this question from a time zone perspective.

Disabling DST is generally not a good thing.  Such features ignore the reality of time zones.  Time zones are defined by individual governments around the world, and those same governments dictate where and when DST is in effect.

As an example, I'm located in Redmond, Washington, USA.  By US law this is located in the Pacific Time zone, which is UTC-8 during standard time and UTC-7 during daylight time.  US law currently allows states to opt-out of DST, which Arizona and Hawaii have done.  But Washington has not, and thus DST is applicable for me here.  Right now (in July) it is 11:00 PDT as I'm writing this.  I cannot just decide for myself that its 10:00 PST.  I would have to relocate to a different time zone to do that.

The time zones in the [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) (TZDB, Olson, etc.) which are used in most systems, including Ubuntu, define distinct areas around the world where local time has agreed since at least 1970.  If there are areas that share the same standard time but differ in whether they get DST or not, or *when* DST applies, then they get their own distinct entry in the TZDB.  In other words, there is no purpose in saying "I want to be in `America/Los_Angeles` without DST" because there is no place in the Pacific time zone that does that.  If you're in the Pitcairn islands (UTC-8 without DST), then you simply use `Pacific/Pitcairn`.

Maybe a clearer example: Most of US Mountain Time uses MST (UTC-7) and MDT (UTC-6), which gets the TZDB identifier `America/Denver`.  Arizona, most of which does not use daylight saving time, uses MST (UTC-7) all year, so it gets its own identifier of `America/Phoenix` in the TZDB.

Then you may ask, well why does Windows have a "Disable DST" feature?  There are a few reasons I can talk publicly about (disclosure: I work at Microsoft, occasionally in this area).

- The Windows time zone feature was originally created with Windows NT.  At that time, the Olson database was around but was not as ubiquitous as it is today.  Microsoft decided to create their own implementation, and thus to this day there are two different sources of time zones data.  TZDB and Microsoft.
- It used to be the case that the Windows time zone data did *not* cover the whole world.  Thus, some Windows users had to rely on this feature to get accurate time.  This changed dramatically with [an update in June 2016](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Daylight-Saving-Time-Time-Zone/Introducing-New-Windows-Time-Zones/ba-p/311124) to align with Microsoft's mission statement of "... every person and every organization on the planet ...".  Today, there is commitment and [policy](https://aka.ms/time) to ensuring accurate time zone data.
- When a government decides to make changes to their time zone (enacting DST, suspending DST, changing DST dates or times, changing a standard time offset, etc.), occasionally the lawmakers make a crucial mistake of not providing enough lead time ([see my blog post on this subject](https://codeofmatt.com/on-the-timing-of-time-zone-changes/)). When that happens, Microsoft may offer suggested temporary guidance on how to get the correct local time until an update can be provided.  Such guidance may include disabling DST or switching to a different time zone.  These recommendations are *always* temporary, thus it becomes debatable whether the feature needs to exist at all.

In general, most Windows users should never disable DST.  If they find themselves needing to do that to get local time correct (outside of the rare case described above), they're probably just not setting their time zone to the correct entry in the first place.

TZDB time zones on Ubuntu and other OSs tend to have shorter update cycles than Windows, and thus are not impacted as heavily by short-notice changes.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I really have no qualms with your reasoning for why "turning off" DST makes virtually no sense. Unfortunately the design requirements document rules all, but I think you've given me a great deal of info to present as to why that specific requirement is foolish and hopefully I will be able to do away with it.

Comment: Indeed.  One of the hardest problems in application development is pushing back on requirements that are based on assumptions that turn out to be short-sighted or incomplete.  That's part of the job.

Comment: How very refreshing to get the info straight from an insider. Thanks for your very well-written answer.